# Eigenfunction expansion in several dimensions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

Im trying to solve the following problem

\begin{aligned}
\psi_xx+\psi_zz &= 0, -h(x,t) < z < \eta(x,t) \\
\psi_z + h_x \psi_x + h_t &= 0, z = -h(x,t) \\
\psi_z - \eta_x \psi_x - \eta_t &= 0, z = \eta(x,t) \\
\psi_t + \frac{1}{2} \nabla \cdot \nabla \psi + gz &= 0, z = \eta(x,t) \\
\psi_x (-L,z,t) &= 0 \\
\psi_x (L,z,t) &= 0 \\
\end{aligned}

First I have tried to linearize the problem, assuming that $ \psi $ and $ \eta $ is small and that h(x,t) is given by $ h(x,t) = h_0 + \xi (x,t) $. I have then

\begin{aligned}
\nabla^2\psi &= 0 \\
\psi_z - \eta_t &= 0, z = 0 \\
\psi_z + \xi_t &= 0, z = -h (x,t)  \\
\psi_t + g \eta &= 0 , z = 0
\end{aligned}

Then I want to try and solve the problem using eigenfunction expansion 
\begin{aligned}
\psi(x,z,t) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \psi_n (z,t) X_n(x) \\
\xi (x,t) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \xi_n (t) X_n(x) \\
\end{aligned}

The $ X_n (x) $ I have found to be

\begin{aligned}
X_n(x) &= \cos(k_n(x + L)),n = 0,1,2... \\
k_n &= \frac{n \pi}{2L} \\ 
\end{aligned}

Now im not sure how to proceed. I think I must do an eigenfunction expansion of $ \psi_n $ but im not sure exactly how to start. The extra dimension confuses me.

Thanks for any help that can be given. The problem comes from water waves.